# Extracting text from a webtable in Watir / Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, nokogiri, watir

I'm trying to extract the data from an Income Statement, url is http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=LMT+Income+Statement&annual

I was unable to find the table using the browser.table(:name, 'blah') or (:id, 'blah'), but had some luck using the xpath with Nokogiri using this code, which picks up after I've initialized everything and browsed to the page:

```
page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
tobj = page_html.xpath('//*[@id="yfncsumtab"]').inner_text
```

Now I'm able to take tobj and pull the data out, but it doesn't do me any good for trying to manipulate the object as a table.  Any suggestions on how to go about storing the table as a variable would help.  I can probably figure out iterating through the rows/columns from there, but I wouldn't mind if you tacked on some code that would do that.

Comment: Can you explain how you want to "manipulate the object as a table"? Do you want to parse it into a 2d array? Perform matrix operations on it?

Comment: I'd like to parse the table into a excel doc that I'd later be putting into a db, etc.  The best way to go about this I though would be to go row by row and insert the data into an excel document.  The reason I want it in an excel doc is so I can transfer it more easily between various formats(as for manipulating the data, I'd be using R and similar packages)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know Watir has xpath support?

```
browser.element(:xpath => '//*[@id="yfncsumtab"]')
```

Comment: I get this error every time I try this.  The located=false message has been haunting me.

#<Watir::HTMLElement:0x4b664164 located=false selector={:xpath=>"//*[@id=\"yfncsumtab\"]"}>

Comment: `located=false` is not an error message. It is a part of the string representation of a ruby object. Please provide more information in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
table = doc.at('table#yfncsumtab')

# iterate through tr's
table.search('tr').each do |tr|
  # do something with tr
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `browser.element(id: "yfncsumtab").text`